# How do I connect to a server behind an socks5 proxy through SSH on mac/linux?

Tags: unix, ssh, socks

I am using the ssh to try to connect to a server behind on remote network. That server is behind a socks5 proxy on the same network. The port of the proxy server is 1080 and the ssh port is 22. However this fails. The debug says that connection is refused on port 22.

I thought it was necessary to install corkscrew so it installed it with homebrew and used [this link as a reference](http://meinit.nl/ssh-through-a-proxy-from-your-apple-mac-os-x)

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/jason/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for XXX.XX.XX
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy.server 1080 XX.XXX.XX.XX 22
debug1: identity file /Users/jason/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
debug1: identity file /Users/jason/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/jason/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
```

Comment: I am not sure if this would be better on server fault, or maybe even the ubuntu stack exchange.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to *connect to* a SOCKS proxy, or are you trying to *create* a SOCKS proxy?

Comment: On the remote server network there is a socks5 proxy server and I am trying to connect to a server behind that socks5 proxy server. I am not trying to create one.

Comment: Corkscrew is for HTTP proxies, not SOCKS proxies.

Comment: @Ignacio - ok. could you give me a little more complete answer on how to use ssh connect?

Comment: Which part of the page I linked to are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Ignacio - Sorry, I didn't realize that was a link. Anyway, the problem has to do with another issue related to VPN. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

```
 ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc -x 127.0.0.1:30000 %h %p' user@destination.com
```

where `127.0.0.1:30000` is the socks5 proxy. Credit: [Jethro Carr](http://www.jethrocarr.com/2013/03/13/ssh-via-socks-proxies/)

Answer (score 3):

you'll need a connect module for ssh which is able to connect through SOCKS.

We use it in our Lab all the time, here's our documentation on how to get it:
https://wiki.enterpriselab.ch/el/public:tools:ssh#using_socks_proxy

In Ubuntu (and I believe so in Debian too) it's available as package, just install with

```
apt-get install connect-proxy
```

it will get installed as /usr/bin/connect-proxy

Answer (score 1):

`-D` creates a SOCKS proxy. If you want to connect via a SOCKS proxy instead then you'll have to use [`connect`](http://bent.latency.net/bent/darcs/goto-san-connect-1.85/src/connect.html) as a proxy command.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question to make it a little clearer.